# Spring security - login by password and temporary password

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I'm trying to implement custom authentication to my service in Spring 2.5 Boot.

Right now I have a typical Spring Security login using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.

What do I need to implement/override to log into account with two passwords? I mean the main password and the temporary password- assigned to the user in case of forgetting (sended via mail)?

note: temporary password has expiry date

Comment: @Toerktumlare these are the business requirements. I already implement this using spring security. I will post my solution for this in free time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented this using spring security.

All you have to do is:

1. Implement UserDetails where you will have password, expiry date and other info like user id or email (you can store here what your project require)
2. Create table with temporary password, expiry date and user id
3. Add feature that assign temporary password to account when user request this.
4. Create interface TemporaryPasswordRepository
5. Create TemporaryPasswordUserDetailsService that implement UserDetailsService and there find the user in TemporaryPasswordRepository in overrided method:

```
 UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException;
```

6. Add impemented UserDetailsService to method in your SecurityConfiguration class:

```
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
  authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(your basic user datails service)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

   authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(TemporaryPasswordUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
}
```

Because spring authorize user when at least one of UserDatailsService match the password then you can now login with 2 passwords.

**Note**: You shoud also implement eg. cron that will delete expired passwords from db.